# Embedding a figure at top right and top left on the first page includepdf

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pdfpages

I want to embedding a figure at top right and top left  on the first page `includepdf`. MWE is below. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{foo2.pdf}}}%
}

\includepdf[pages={1-}, scale=1.00, angle=00]{foo.pdf}

\end{document}
```

**Edited**

After the comment of  @touhami, I am able to get the fig on top right and top left but getting borders which I want to remove. Any hint this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: package  [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)

Comment: Thanks @touhami for your comment. Would appreciate if you provide an example too. Thanks

Comment: i'll try to do :-)

Comment: Please @touhami, see my edits and help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce the issue, your code works fine for me. may be borders are part of the figure?

Comment: `\includegraphics[trim= 1mm 1mm 1mm 1mm, clip, width=1.5cm]{myfoto}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run `\pdfcrop` on foo2.pdf or remove the whitespace in the pdf in some other way.  Then replace `foo2.pdf` in `\includegraphics` with `foo2-crop.pdf`.